# Massive insertions from one big table to other related tables

Tags: postgresql, insertion

**Into**:

Currently i have scraped all the data into one PostgreSQL 'Bigtable' table(there are about 1.2M rows). Now i need to split the design into separate tables which all have dependency on the Bigtable. Some of the tables might have subtables. The model looks pretty much like snowflake.

**Problem**:

What would be best option to inserting data into tables? I thought to make the insertion with functions written in 'SQL' or PLgSQL. But the problem is still with auto-generated ID-s.

Also if you know what tools might make this problem solving easier then post!

//**Edit** i have added example, this not the real case just for illustration[image: .]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the nature of the problem with auto-generated IDs? There are solutions, no doubt.

Comment: Alternate to consider...PostgreSQL has some limitations around 1 process = 1 processor (plz correct me if I'm wrong here, but there is no SQL method to have postgres allocate multiple processors to one process, need to use software such as PGpooler for that).  1.2M records in a fact table like the bistable here isn't the largest, but if speed is a concern and you are on data warehouse that has multiple processors on it consider using an ETL tool to help you with what you are doing here (I'm using Pentaho which is free, Data Stage works as well, any ETL tool really).

Comment: Also not the biggest fan of using 'distinct' in the manner you have here...there may be a large performance gain to be found in rewriting those queries to use joins instead of distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.2 M rows is not too much. The best tool is sql script executed from console "psql". If you have a some newer version of Pg, then you can use inline functions (DO statement) when it is necessary. But probably the most useful command is INSERT INTO SELECT statement.

```
-- file conversion.sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS f1 CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE f1(a int, b int);
INSERT INTO f1
   SELECT x1, y1 
      FROM data
     WHERE x1 = 10;

    ...

-- end file

psql mydb -f conversion.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use a psql function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION migration() RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   currentProductId   INTEGER;
   currentUserId      INTEGER;
   currentReg         RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR currentReg IN
     SELECT * FROM bigtable
   LOOP
     -- Product
     SELECT productid INTO currentProductId 
     FROM product 
     WHERE name = currentReg.product_name;

     IF currentProductId IS NULL THEN
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES (''' || currentReg.product_name || ''') RETURNING productid' 
        INTO currentProductId;
     END IF;

     -- User
     SELECT userid INTO currentUserId 
     FROM user
     WHERE first_name = currentReg.first_name and last_name = currentReg.last_name;

     IF currentUserId IS NULL THEN
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name) VALUES (''' || currentReg.first_name || ''', ''' || currentReg.last_name || ''') RETURNING userid' 
        INTO currentUserId;

        -- Insert into userAdded too with: currentUserId and currentProductId
        [...]

     END IF;

     -- Rest of tables
     [...]    

    END LOOP;
  RETURN 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from migration();
```

In this case it's assumed that each table runs its own primary key sequence and I have reduced the number of fields in the tables to simplify.
I hope you have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a function for this (unless I misunderstood your problem)

If your id columns are all defined as `serial` column (i.e. they automatically generate the values), then this can be done with simple INSERT statements. This assumes that the target tables are all empty.

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname)
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname
FROM bigtable;

INSERT INTO category (name)
SELECT DISTINCT category_name 
FROM bigtable;

-- the following assumes a column categoryid in the product table 
-- which is not visible from your screenshot
INSERT INTO product (product_name, description, categoryid)
SELECT DISTINCT b.product_name, b.description, c.categoryid 
FROM bigtable b
  JOIN category c ON c.category_name = b.category_name;

INSERT INTO product_added (product_productid, user_userid)
SELECT p.productid, u.userid
FROM bigtable b
  JOIN product p ON p.product_name = b.product_name
  JOIN users u ON u.firstname = b.firstname AND u.lastname = b.lastname
```